# NSString with fixed length

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, objective-c-category

I want an nsstring object that can only store specified lenght of character in it.

If it exceeds it should get truncated from left. For example if i set lenght to 5, and I enter value as Ileana then it should store leana.

I tried by making a category on nsstring but i am out of ideas :

```
-(void)setMaximumLength:(NSInteger)length;{
    if ([self length]>length) {
        NSLog(@"exxed");
    }

}
```

Please suggest what should I do? I hve one thng in my mind I need to observe the string size but how to do in a category, and which notification will be called?

Comment: Sounds for me like a good use of an individual setter for this property. In the setter you could truncate the string.

Comment: Agreed. It seems very strange to have a special kind of string that has a maximum length, rather than saying that the a given object's "foo" property (which happens to be a string) has a maximum length. Ileana, can you explain the use case for this? Since NSStrings are immutable, there's no point at which you could call the above method (or anything like it).

Comment: NSString objects aren't mutable. You can't truncate them. You can use `substringFromIndex:` or `substringToIndex:` for a similar effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds suspiciously like formatting for display or processing user input or something like that rather than an actual constraint you want to impose on strings in general. In that case, an NSFormatter class or a bit of code in some specific controller property setter would be a good idea.

But if you really want this to be on the string itself, you either need to provide a method like `stringByTruncatingToLength:` on NSString or you need to switch to using NSMutableString everywhere, because NSStrings cannot be modified at all and thus a `setMaximumLength:` method would be kind of meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism of truncation can be implemented like this:(for a NSString property of a custom class)

```
-(void)setName:(NSString*)newName
{
  if([newName length]> maxLength)
{
   newName = [newName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([newName length] - maxLength, maxLength];
}
   _name = newName;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of NSString being a class cluster and the consequences for subclassing that brings?

Comment: you are talking of subclassing NSString but the code doesnt show it

Comment: Yes.my fault. the code above shows how to implement a setter for a property "Name" of type NSString in my custom class

Comment: do you know how to subclass a class cluster?

Comment: yes, subclassing class cluster completly differs from subclassing usual classes and here NSString should not be subclassed.

Comment: so why do you tell OP to subclass NSString?